# GeoPackage to Shapefile export

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, geometry, geopackage

When creating a GeoPackage vector layer in QGIS 3.10.x, it provides the following geometry types: **Point, Line, Polygon, Multipoint, MultiLine, MultiPolygon, CompoundCurve, CurvePolygon, MultiCurve, MultiSurface**.

And when creating a shapefile-layer only the geometry points: **Point, Line, Polygon, Multipoint** are available.

How are the geometry types **MultiLine, MultiPolygon, CompoundCurve, CurvePolygon, MultiCurve and MultiSurface** represented when exporting a GeoPackage layer to a Shapefile?

Comment: Shapefile does not distinct multilines and multipolygons so they are stored as lines and polygons. Shapefile does not support curved geometries https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf. I guess that curved geometries are converted into linear ones that would mean that the shape of geometries is not totally preserved but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I created a GeoPackage layer with "CompoundCurve" geometry, added a "circle from two points" and then Save As a shapefile and discovered it is a Line String geometry shapefile.

Here's a GeoPackage with a circular line feature in it. If I use the vertex tool to edit it I can edit the ends and the radius, showing it is being stored as  circle parts. If I export to Shapefile I get a Line String feature and the vertex tool shows the circle as being made of small line sections. I'm not sure where the size of the line segments to approximate a circle is controlled.

[image]

I'm getting a few odd errors when trying to do much with this CompoundCurve layer so perhaps its a bit experimental for now...